# JS de um documento funcionar dentro do html do iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Boa tarde galera!

Eu tenho meu site por exemplo, que tem a pagina normal que toda pagina tem, html, head, body, etc... Dentro dessa minha pagina, tem um iframe, esse iframe puxa outro html de uma outra pagina, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <iframe>
         <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <div class="teste">Teste</div>
            </body>
         </html>
     </iframe>
     <script>
          $('.teste'); /*Está me retornando null*/
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

O problema é esse, eu não posso mexer no html desse iframe, não tenho acesso a ele. Se eu tentar pegar o valor daquele div teste ali com um `document.querySelector('.teste')` com o próprio jQuery com o `$('teste');` não funciona, pois aquele document ali se refere ao meu documento (o que eu tenho acesso) o documento do iframe eu não consigo.

Sempre está me retornando null.

Como eu posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa selecionar primeiro o `iframe` e depois usar `contents`:

```
$("iframe").contents().find(".teste");
```

Se iframe tiver um ID melhor:

```
$("#idIframe").contents().find(".teste");
```

Referência: [api.jquery.com/contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)